# Sending multiple Excel exports to zipped folder on user's desktop

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

I'm not familiar with Access or VBA in the slightest, but unfortunately it's required to use for an export/import set I have going with another program. Below I have the three tables I need exported to Excel, but what I would like to know is if it possible to save all three in a zip to the current user's desktop.

```
Function Macro11()
On Error GoTo Macro11_Err

    DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputTable, "UB_Donors", "ExcelWorkbook(*.xlsx)", "", False, "", , acExportQualityPrint
    DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputTable, "UB_DonationHistory", "ExcelWorkbook(*.xlsx)", "", False, "", , acExportQualityPrint
    DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputTable, "UB_DonationValues", "ExcelWorkbook(*.xlsx)", "", False, "", , acExportQualityPrint


Macro11_Exit:
    Exit Function

Macro11_Err:
    MsgBox Error$
    Resume Macro11_Exit

End Function
```

What can I do to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible.

You can use my `Zip` function found at **GitHub** in my project [VBA.Compress](https://github.com/GustavBrock/VBA.Compress) in module `FileCompress.bas`:

```
' Zip a file or a folder to a zip file/folder using Windows Explorer.
' Default behaviour is similar to right-clicking a file/folder and selecting:
'   Send to zip file.
'
' Parameters:
'   Path:
'       Valid (UNC) path to the file or folder to zip.
'   Destination:
'       (Optional) Valid (UNC) path to file with zip extension or other extension.
'   Overwrite:
'       (Optional) Leave (default) or overwrite an existing zip file.
'       If False, the created zip file will be versioned: Example.zip, Example (2).zip, etc.
'       If True, an existing zip file will first be deleted, then recreated.
'
'   Path and Destination can be relative paths. If so, the current path is used.
'
'   If success, 0 is returned, and Destination holds the full path of the created zip file.
'   If error, error code is returned, and Destination will be zero length string.
'
' Early binding requires references to:
'
'   Shell:
'       Microsoft Shell Controls And Automation
'
'   Scripting.FileSystemObject:
'       Microsoft Scripting Runtime
'
' 2022-04-20. Gustav Brock. Cactus Data ApS, CPH.
'
Public Function Zip( _
    ByVal Path As String, _
    Optional ByRef Destination As String, _
    Optional ByVal Overwrite As Boolean) _
    As Long
```

> < snip - too much code to post here>

Full documentation:

[Zip and unzip files and folders with VBA the Windows Explorer way](https://www.experts-exchange.com/articles/31130/Zip-and-unzip-files-and-folders-with-VBA-the-Windows-Explorer-way.html?preview=yvSy86kgNss%3D)